# Jmeter response search

Tags: jmeter, extractor

We have a html

12345

I want to extract 12345 through CSS/JQuery and tried the following .
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_WinLabel").html()
But it is not working in jmeter and but and able to get the value if i try the same query in html file.
I tried to print the value suing BeanShell PostProcessor and getting error.
Please suggest where I am wrong.

Comment: Update your question with response part showing some previous and following tags

Comment: Regular Expression Extractor should work fine.